# Why is the bell tolling when I'm playing online?

Tags: dark-souls

Every now and then I hear a bell tolling in Dark Souls.  Is this other people ringing the awakening bell?  Do I gain any buffs from this event (like I do when someone kindles a bonfire)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [according to](http://www.gamespot.com/dark-souls/answers/undead-parish-bell-ringing-297740) [other players](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/606312-dark-souls/60735334) of the game, you'll hear the bell ringing if you're playing online and someone else online rings the bell.

It doesn't appear to have any effect on your game, although the interactions between games in Dark Souls is a bit mysterious and I don't have any authoritative sources confirming this.